# How does Javascript implement date comparison operator?

Tags: javascript, datetime, operator-overloading, operators

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493018/49942) says,

> The [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) will do what you want - construct one for each date, then compare them using the `>`, `<`, `<=` or `>=`.

I don't see this functionality mentioned on the referenced page.

- Is this browser-specific behaviour, or a standard feature of the language?
- If Date is a javascript "object", and javascript doesn't support operator overloading, then how is this behaviour of the `>`, `<`, `<=` or `>=` operator on Date objects implemented? I mean, is it defined on `Date.prototype`, does it happen because some implicit conversion is defined (e.g. from an object to a number or a string), is it a special-case for Date objects added to the Javascript language interpreter/run-time, or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you use an object where you'd usually expect a number (addition, subtraction, greater/lower comparison) the *valueOf* method is called to turn the object into a primitive:

```
{ valueOf: () => 2 }.valueOf() // 2
//or not explicitly called:
+ { valueOf: () => 2 } // 2
//using the compare operator:
{ valueOf: () => 2 } < { valueOf: ()=>3 } //true as 2 < 3
```

So when you compare Dates this happens too. Since the *Date.prototype.valueOf* method returns the Milliseconds since 1970, you can use it to compare two dates...

```
new Date().valueOf();
//or
+new Date(); 
//or
new Date() < new Date();
```

Comment: Thank you. Also I found more details in the description of [The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5).

Answer (score 2):

> Is this browser-specific behaviour, or a standard feature of the language?

It's a standard feature.

> If `Date` is a javascript "object", and javascript doesn't support operator overloading, then how is this behaviour of the `>`, `<`, `<=` or `>=` operator on `Date` objects implemented?

Because of the way `Date` implements [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) and [`Symbol.toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) ([`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is related, but not for the specific operators you mentioned). Those three methods are used in the process of implicitly converting an object to a primitive value by the [OrdinaryToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive) abstract operation in the specification, which is used by operators when they need a primitive value (like a string or number) but they receive an object.

In particular, `Date` implements `valueOf` by returning its underlying time value (milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970 at midnight GMT). So `date1 >= date2` invokes `valueOf` on each of the dates, hinting that a number is preferred, which gets the time value (a number) from the dates, and then compares them. More below.

A duplicate of this question asked:

> Can we do it for any class?

Yes, as of ES2015 this is all standard and `Date` is no longer special like it used to be (the way it was special was relatively minor, more below). For example:

```js
class MyThing {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    valueOf() {
        return this.value;
    }

    toString() {
        return String(this.value);
    }
}

const a = new MyThing(27);
const b = new MyThing(42);
console.log(`a < b? ${a < b}`);   // a < b? true
console.log(`b < a? ${b < a}`);   // b < a? false
console.log(`b - a = ${b - a}`);  // b - a = 15
console.log(`a + b = ${a + b}`);  // a + b = 69
```

(The above leaves out something `Date` has, more in a moment.)

When an operator or similar needs to convert an object to a primitive, it uses the object's "to primitive" operation, optionally providing a "hint" about what it would prefer (a string, a number, or no preference). The relational operators prefer numbers, as do all the pure math operators like `-`. The `+` operator, being both addition and string concatenation, doesn't provide a hint so the object's default is used. Almost built-in objects default to number if there's no hint; `Date` and `Symbol` default to string instead. That used to just be built into the logic of the specification's operation (for `Date`; `Symbol` didn't exist then), but it's now handled via the `Symbol.toPrimitive` method instead, which an object can override to provide its own handling of being converted to a primitive.

If we wanted `MyThing` to default to string instead of number like `Date` does, we'd add the `Symbol.toPrimitive` method (I've also added `console.log`s to `valueOf` and `toString` to show which is used for the operations):

```js
class MyThing {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    valueOf() {
        console.log("valueOf");
        return this.value;
    }

    toString() {
        console.log("toString");
        return String(this.value);
    }

    [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
        if (hint === "number") {
            return this.valueOf();
        }
        // "default" or "number"
        return this.toString();
    }
}

const a = new MyThing(27);
const b = new MyThing(42);
console.log(`a < b? ${a < b}`);   // a < b? true
console.log(`b < a? ${b < a}`);   // b < a? false
console.log(`b - a = ${b - a}`);  // b - a = 15
console.log(`a + b = ${a + b}`);  // a + a = "2742"
```

Notice how `a + b` is doing string concatenation now, where in the first snippet it was doing addition. That's because we changed the default behavior to prefer strings over numbers.