# How does Date in Javascript overload +, -, >= and <= operators?

Tags: javascript, operator-overloading

I have noticed that you can compare dates like this in Javascript:

```js
const a = new Date('2020')
const b = new Date('2019')

a > b    // true
a >= b   // true
a < b    // false
```

But `Date` is an object:

```js
typeof a // object
```

How does this work? Can we do it for any class?

Comment: override the `.valueOf` method in your object

Comment: It doesn’t overload them. The operators coerce the object to primitive types. `Date`s have `toString`, `valueOf`, and `Symbol.toPrimitive` properties. Read the [spec](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan) for details.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+how+can+operators+be+used+with+Date) of [How does Javascript implement date comparison operator?](/q/43845122/4642212).

Comment: @ rksh1997 - I've moved [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68699694/157247) to the dupetarget.